# How to configure multi-module projects in Spring without repeating yml config file props?

Tags: spring-config

I have three projects. Proj 3 depends on Proj 2 and Proj 2 depends on Proj 1. Each project uses Spring Boot and is configured with yml files. I don't want to repeat the yml configuration of Proj 1 in Proj 2. Likewise, I don't want to repeat the  in yml config of Proj 2 and Proj 1 in Proj 3.

How can this be done? As far as I know, I can only have one `application.yml` file (in use) across all three project.

Comment: I have the solution but it's application.properties file. do you want it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to change my .properties to .yml and It works for me.

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Profile("staging")
    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties() {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        YamlPropertiesFactoryBean yaml = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean();
        yaml.setResources(new ClassPathResource("common-staging.yml"));
        propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setProperties(yaml.getObject());
        return propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I already know how to do this with properties files. I need to use yml files.